# Do new playthroughs require new characters?

Tags: diablo-ii

I've never played Diablo 2 before.  If I beat the game and then restart on a harder difficulty, will I be reusing the character from my first round through the game or making a new one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every character has to go through the game modes on its own. Every character starts in normal, once that is beaten can then enter nightmare with all his gear and levels intact. After beating nightmare you can enter hell.

All the difficulties contain the same monsters/areas/quests. The map will have a different layout, but blood raven will always be there. Just as the countess. And all the other bosses.
Monsters do NOT scale to your level at all. They get extra immunities/resistances in higher difficulties. (for example fallen are immune to fire damage in hell)

If you somehow get a level 1 character into nightmare or hell he will be one hit killed by everything.

Comment: @ColeBusby story progression was never tied to your account. It would even be stupid to even allow a lvl 1 in hell. He can't use any of the items from the shops, can't afford them, can't equip them and can't kill anything out of town.

Comment: @ColeBusby you could never jump a char straight to hell without doing the quests, hence the need for rushes.  However, its possib;e to be a very low level in hell so you can leech xp super fast in places like chaos sanctuary

Comment: @arperum what's the current game version? My knowledge was from 2004&6 when I last played.

Comment: @ColeBusby My knowledge is from years ago too, from around patch 1.11 at latest or something. After that i went into mods.

Comment: @Arperum To the best of my knowledge, Fallen and all related monsters have always been immune to **Fire** damage in Hell. The Act V “guest” Fallen may be immune to cold (the shamans shoot *glacial blast* instead of *fire bolt* anyway), but those are an exception.

Comment: @KRyan I'll fix it, I remember having stupid high difficulty with A1Hell with my pure ice-sorc.

Comment: The current official build of D2X is 1.13. As far as getting into Hell with a lvl 1 character, it's impossible; even if you were rushed through the whole thing, by being a member of the party completing the quests, you'd gain enough experience to level at least a few times.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you will.

But don't forget that there are some "penalties" in higher difficulties. In *Nightmare* you will get **-40%** to all resistances and in *Hell* it will be **-100%**.

Also don't forget that the levels of the monsters are higher in higher difficulties. For example, a *[Pit Lord](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Megademon)* will have level 27 in *Normal* difficulty and level 83 in *Hell*. Also it's hit points will grow from 200-ish to 9-14k-ish.

And if you hack you character or if you play online, you can even get a level 1 character in *Hell*. In this case I'd recommend you joining public *Chaos Sanctuary* runs till level 20, then public *Cow Level* runs till 25, then again *Chaos Sanctuary* runs till 60, then do *Ancients* quest in *Hell* and level up in public [*Baal*](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Baal) [runs](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Guide:High_Level_Baal_Runs_to_99_v1.10,_by_jjscud_and_Reborn).

Source: level 99 [*Battle.Net*](http://eu.battle.net/en/) paladin

Comment: forgot to add: to get a level 1 character in *Hell* you will **have to** find a person and a *gater* (unless you are playing classic where *gaters* are not needed).